# columnWidth of RangeFormat is giving some random number instead giving the actual width in excel-addin office-js

Tags: reactjs, office-js, excel-addins

we are working on developing excel add-in using office-JS and We are using "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" official production API's.

we have set the columnWidth as "20" from the excel but while getting it using office-js APIwe are getting some random number.

My sample code is as below -

```
const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

let range = sheet.getRange("C3:L12");
range.load("format, columnCount");

await context.sync();

console.log(range.format.columnWidth);
```

OUTPUT: `125`

Here output should be 20, but the API is returning 125. Also, one thing the columnWidth is behaving differently on Mac and Windows OS.

The API's are working fine for the rowHeight, whatever we are setting in the excel we are getting in the API response, but for columnWidh we are getting some random number.

**Can anyone please help and let us know how the columnWidth is calculated in office-js API's?**

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the unit difference.

On an Excel spreadsheet, you can set a column width of 0 to 255, with one unit equal to the width of one character that can be displayed in a cell formatted with the standard font. If a column's width is set to zero (0), the column is hidden.

On a new worksheet, the default width of all columns is 8.43 characters.
When you use Excel JS API, we will return in pixel.

However, the actual width that you see on the screen varies, depending on the width of the font defined for the Normal style of your workbook. Changing the default font also changes the column width. This behavior occurs because of the way that Excel stores the column width information for individual fonts. This article discusses how column widths are determined.

Detail can be found at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/determine-column-widths) document

Comment: Thank you @Raymond Lu. It means we can't verify it from Office-Js API. I wanted to check the width match in my code to perform certain functions, but seems it is not possible.

Comment: Maybe you could try to change the unit setting in option/advance, see whether it helps?

Comment: Can you please let me know which units need to be changed?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-measurement-rulers-on-a-worksheet-50cc68ad-64f1-4607-b0e8-d16014609670, here is a post for changing the units in excel